# Change CSS property of range slider thumb via JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Similar questions have been asked before but none of them answer my question.

**Question**

How could I change CSS properties dynamically on a range slider (`::-webkit-slider-thumb` / `::-moz-range-thumb`) when the slider position changes?

Background: I have a styled range thumb with a background image on it. When I slide I want to change the background position to show different parts of the background image based on the position. The CSS code I currently have is just the basic setup and only works in Chrome (as this is currently just a playground):

```
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/236x/22/58/74/22587435a1a6dae08711cdb64ee7efb3.jpg);
  background-position: 00px -10px;
  background-size: 200px 300px;
}
```

I have not found a way to change the `background-position` property via JQuery or Vanilla JS.

[Here](https://codepen.io/Vepth/pen/zYrPZqv) is a Fiddle I set up that currently only toggles a class an the input itself which is far away from the desired result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have defined a variable for the root element. And I updated the `background-position` according to the slider's value.

```js
const range = document.getElementById('range');
const rangeV = document.getElementById('rangeValue');

const setValue = ()=>{
    const newValue = Number( (range.value - range.min) * 100 / (range.max - range.min) );
    const newPosition = 35 - (newValue * 0.7);
    rangeV.style.left = `calc(${newValue}% + (${newPosition}px))`;
  
  /* added */
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--bg-pos-x", `${newValue}px`);
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--bg-pos-y", `${newValue}px`);
  /****/
  
  rangeV.innerHTML = `<span>${range.value}%</span>`;
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", setValue);
range.addEventListener('input', setValue);
```

```css
/* added */
html {
  --bg-pos-x:00px;
  --bg-post-y:-10px;
}
/***/

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 50px;
}

.range-wrap {
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.ticks {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.ticks p {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1px;
  background: #D3D3D3;
  height: 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 20px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #005DFF;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  border: solid 4px #005DFF;
  border-color: #005DFF #005DFF transparent transparent;
  border-radius: 100% 100% 100% 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-44%) rotate(-45deg);
          transform: translateY(-44%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.range-value {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.range-value span {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: #0008d7;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 99;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/236x/22/58/74/22587435a1a6dae08711cdb64ee7efb3.jpg);
  background-position:  var(--bg-pos-x) var(--bg-pos-y);
  background-size: 200px 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="range-wrap">
      <div class="ticks">
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <div class="range-value" id="rangeValue"></div>
      <input id="range" type="range" min="1" max="10" value="1" step="0.1">
    </div>
```

Comment: Incredible! I have never used variables in CSS (only new it from SASS) but this gave me a good idea how to create a solution. Well done!